# Поочередное нажатие на кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста. Как сделать что бы при нажатии на "Зона 1" потом на "Зона 2", а потом на "Удалить", alert выводил только Зона 2? Я так понимаю событие нажатия на region-delit копятся, но не знаю как их можно подчистить.

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/y3e8vw3q/)

```js
$('body').on('click', '.region-edit', function() {
 var text = $(this).text();
  $('#del_btn').click(function() {
    alert(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 1</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 2</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 3</button>

<button id="del_btn" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small">Удалить</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странное поведение кода, внутри обработчика нажатия на кнопку <kbd>Удалить</kbd> обоснованно. Что получается, что вы внутри обработчика клика на `'.region-edit'` создаете обработчик клика на кнопку <kbd>Удалить</kbd>. То есть, сколько раз вы кликните на `'.region-edit'`, столько раз вы и *создадите* этот блок кода:

```
$('#del_btn').click(function() {
  alert(text);
});
```

Что в последствии приведет к тому, что кликнув на кнопку <kbd>Удалить</kbd> вы раз за разом вызовете обработчики в той последовательности, в которой они были добавлены. Чтобы код выполнял то, что вы указали в своем вопросе - достаточно вынести, к примеру, глобальную переменную, если хотите хранить в JS-коде, либо можно хранить в `hidden` на странице, либо в аттрибутах, в общем, подходов масса, более наглядно будет, если вынесем переменную `var text = "";` в которой будет храниться текст последнего кликнутого `'.region-edit'`.

Что касается обработчика нажатия на кнопку <kbd>Удалить</kbd> - его следует вынести из обработчика клика на `'.region-edit'`, просто положите его рядом, чтобы был один его экземпляр.

```js
var text = "";

$('body').on('click', '.region-edit', function() {
  text = $(this).text();
});

$('#del_btn').click(function() {
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 1</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 2</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 3</button>

<button id="del_btn" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small">Удалить</button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо всем участникам. Особенно автору данного ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция `$(function() { ... });` эквивалентна следующей:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
});
```

Конструкция `text && alert(text);` эквивалентна следующей:

```
if (text) {
  alert(text);
}
```

С этим условием `alert()` сработает только после нажатия одной из `Зона #` кнопок.

Пример:

```js
$(function() {
  var text = '';
  $('.region-edit').click(function() {
    text = $(this).text();
  });
  $('#del_btn').click(function() {
    text && alert(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 1</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 2</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 3</button>

<button id="del_btn" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small">Удалить</button>
```

Comment: ну хоть парочку слов объяснения можно почему именно это надо делать и что не так было у ТС?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, ну грубо говоря клиент нажимает на кнопку "зона 1" и нажимает удалить. Сейчас выходит что нажимая на зону 1 и зону 2 (вдруг захочет поменять решение) , а потом на удалить, удаляет 2 кнопки вместо последней. Что за ТС?

Comment: @Максим ТС - это ты .. Топик Стартер)) ....я от ответчика просил объяснения, чтоб ты понял что у тебя не так и что в этом коде  в ответе невнятное творится.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, а ну это да)

Answer (score 0):

Немного чистого js и творчества:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let button_text;
let button_id;

Array.from(buttons).forEach(function(el, i) {
 
 el.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(el.id == 'del_btn' ) {
   if(button_text !== undefined) {
    document.querySelector('.red').classList.add('down');
    console.log('delete', button_text)
   }
   
  } else {
   for(let value of buttons) {
    if(value.classList.contains('red')) {
     value.classList.remove('red')
    } else {
     el.classList.add('red')
    } 
   }
   button_text = el.innerText;
   console.log(el.id, el.innerText)
  }  
 })
})
```

```css
.red {
 background: red;
}
.down {
 background: inherit;
 transform: scale(0.75);
 opacity: 0.75;
 transition: 400ms;
}
```

```html
<button id="Button_1" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 1</button>
<button id="Button_2" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 2</button>
<button id="Button_3" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small region-edit">Зона 3</button>

<button id="del_btn" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small">Удалить</button>
```